# Fastest Array Comparison

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, comparison

I have two sorted arrays (can be ArrayLists, Collections, or any other data format) of unique values. What is the fastest way to compare them? The goal is to remove all values that are present on both lists.

Start with:

```
int [] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int [] b = {1, 2, 3, 6, 7};
```

End with:

```
a = {4, 5}
b = {6, 7}
```

Comment: you can easily compare in O(n) worst case

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a modified version of the merge step in [MergeSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

- get an iterator for each array
- compare values of the iterators
- if equal, increment both
- if not equal, put lesser value into array of unique values and increment only that iterator
- repeat until end of an array is met
- if any left in other array, those are unique

Comment: Isn't that algorithm O(N)?

Answer (score 1):

```
List list = Arrays.asList(a);

list.retainAll(b); //now list has {1, 2, 3}

List result = Arrays.asList(a).removeAll(list); //it now has 4, 5. For b do the same
```

Comment: This is the shortest code probably, but it can't be the most efficient.